# Post an answer that you really like

Tags: discussion

To make it more interesting, here are two restrictions - the answer should be by another user, the question also should not have been asked by you.

Answer (score 4):

I really like the answer by the user *Be Happy* on the question:

[What exactly was the Chakra-Vyuha or Padma-Vyuha in the Mahabharata, and why did Abhimanyu fail to break it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/550/what-exactly-was-the-chakra-vyuha-or-padma-vyuha-in-the-mahabharata-and-why-did)

The answer explains the working of a ChakraVyuha graphically which is very helpful. The answer is neither too long or too short. It also has a good mix of personal thought and references.

Comment: Yeah it is one of the best posts.

Answer (score 3):

This is my new favorite answer by the user @Tezz :)

[How were the Trimurti born answer - The Unity behind the trinity](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13639/119)

Why?

Everyone knows that Brahma, Vishnu and Maheshvara are One, however nobody has the in depth knowledge to read through all the texts.

Therefore each person simply reads the parts that are favorable to his/her idealogy and puts that up as the final truth.

However Truth is One, and All Gods are indeed One.

Ekam Sat, Viprah Badhuda Vadanti!
(Truth is One, Sages call it by various names)

These are the kind of posts that make me want to say 'Absolutely Fantastic!' :).